# Website get stuck after upgradation of Magento 1.9.3.3 to 1.9.2.4

Tags: database, magento-1

Sometime my site get stuck on `proceed to checkout` and `add to cart` after upgrading magento 1.9.3.3 from 1.9.2.2

Sometime `add to cart` button does not work. Same in admin when i try to create/save new product. It shows loading then i refresh admin and save again, it saves. It also happening in many events like creating new products, click on order section and cleaning cache. Re-indexing is also taking lot of time.

can anyone help, how to resolve these issues?